# How to upload multiple images from a folder to S3 Bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to implement code in python for uploading multiple images into an S3 bucket.
With only one image I can do it normally, but when I implemented this for loop, the following error started to appear:

```sh
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.jpg'
```

And this is the function I've been able to develop so far with the help of AWS documentation:

```py
def upload_file(path, bucket, object_name=None):
    """
    Upload files to an S3 bucket

    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param path: Path of the folder with files to upload
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified, then filename is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # S3 bucket connection
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    # List files from a folder
    files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

    try:
        # Upload the image
        for file in files:
            s3_client.upload_file(file, bucket, object_name)

    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False

    return True
```

If anyone has any ideas to solve this problem, I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you also show us the input to the `upload_file` function when you call it?

Comment: `listdir` doesn't include the `path` in the resulting filenames.  You need to `os.path.join(path, f)` inside your `files` comprehension.

Comment: @jellycsc This one
```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    upload_file('/home/caleb/Pictures/foo/', 'bucket-name')
```

Comment: It looks like you may have copied this code from [this example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html) and modified it incorrectly, specifically with respect to the case when object_name is not provided.

Comment: Truth. For some reason I deleted the condition line from `object_name`. Now I fixed it. Thanks @jarmod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
```

to

```
files = [join(path, f) for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
```

should resolve your issue.

Comment: I understood now what I was doing wrong.

But now the following botocore exception has risen:

`Invalid type for parameter Key, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

It is getting this problem because of `object_name` being equal to `None`. I don't understand the reason for the error, as it is in this way in the documentation by default. I will try to understand how to fix this.

Anyway, thank you very much.